# Inverse of $.param for PHP

Tags: php, jquery

There is a function in jQuery, `$.param`, that takes an object (can be a nested object too) and converts it to a string suitable for `GET` usage.

I was wondering if there is a PHP function that would take that string and convert it back to an array (or nested array, if that was the case). Is there such a function?

EDIT:

I'm sending this JS object (after `$.param()`-ing it):

```
{"categories": [90000]}
```

I'm reading it on the server side from `$_GET` and then I'm passing it to `parse_str`.

I also have a test code that recreates the expected PHP array.

The entire thing looks like:

```
$filter = $_GET["my_array"];
parse_str($filters, $_filters);
error_log(print_r($_filters, true), 4);
$x = [
    "categories" => [
        90000
    ]
];
error_log(print_r($x, true), 4);
```

The output of that code is:

```
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90000
        ) 
)


(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90000
        ) 
)
```

So I assume they are identical. But then I'm passing that array to Yii's `findAll` method and it's working only with `$x`.

Maybe `parse_str` is mixing plain arrays and associative arrays when parsing and that is why `findAll` is not working?

Comment: `parse_url()` as @samv points out, or `parse_str()` depending on what the input is from.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be looking for [`parse_url`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) or [`parse_str`](https://php.net/parse_str) that Jon Stirling mentioned.

Bear in mind that all the query parameters will already exist in the `$_GET` global.

Usage for the query part of the URL.

```
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it's working... but... I have a problem and I'm not really sure if it's my fault or a bug in `parse_url`. I'm sending this JS object: `{"categories": [90000]}` which then turns out as http://pastebin.com/AK7kHe5D . You'll see that the output of both `error_log` calls is the same, but the function that I'm passing the data doesn't work with `$filters`, but it does with `$x`. Maybe `parse_url` is mixing plain arrays and associative arrays when converting?

Comment: @alexandernst I'm slightly confused what does your query string look like? Update your question with what the JS outputs and its request content

Comment: @alexandernst what do you mean sending the JS object, can you please add the HTTP request that gets sent to your server. From there I can provide a solution

Comment: I'm just making a request with what `$.param()` is returning, aka. `window.location.href = "http://test.com/?my_array=" + $.param({ categories: [90000] });`

Comment: Oh, I saw the error. `parse_str` is, incorrectly, parsing `90000` as a string instead of an int. Is there any fix for this? (keep in mind that this is just a test case, I can't cast to int each and every single request).

Comment: You could recursively walk through the array and cast any integer values (`is_integer`) to an int (`(int) "9000"`). You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php to walk through it and apply you're own function (mentioned above).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78107/discussion-between-alexandernst-and-samv).

Comment: But that will cast every possible integer to an int (which is wrong). There is a difference between an integer `9` and a string `9`. Can't parse_str handle that the same way json_decode does?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `parse_str`:

```
$serializedData = $_GET['data'];
$unserializedData = array();

parse_str($serializedData, $unserializedData);

print_r($unserializedData);
```